# C++. Запись значений в массив

Tags: c, c++

Изучаю указатели в C++. Вопрос наверное детский) Объясните плиз, как работает запись в первом случае. Во втором ясно, им пользовался. А первый.. ar - массив, i - число.. Как-то не укладывается в моей голове, как оно работает

```
float ar[999];
for(i=0; i<n; i++) {
    printf("Введите элемент %d: ", i+1);
    scanf("%f",ar+i); // 1
    scanf("%f",&ar[i]); // 2
}
```

Comment: Разве в первом случае вообще верно?!

ar - можно сказать не массив, а указатель на массив (на структуру данных в памяти).
&ar[i] - указывает что надо взять адрес i-той ячейки в массиве.
В первом случае скорее всего неверно работает, и записывается мимо указанного массива, куда-нить в [адрес_массива_в_памяти+смещение по i].

Comment: @Rang, оба `scanf()` **абсолютно верные**. 

Просто разная синтаксическая форма записи адреса ячейки памяти.

--

@inferus-vv, почитайте про *адресную арифметику* в Си. 

В данном случае `ar` это адрес начала (т.е. адрес ar[0]) массива. 

Можете убедиться:

    printf ("%p %p\n", ar, &ar[0]);

Если к адресу прибавить число, то исполнимый адрес (в байтах) в Си вычисляется вот так

    char *dst_addr = (char *)src_addr + i * sizeof(*src_addr);

имеется в виду, что тип данных на которые указывает `src_addr` нам известен.

Comment: @avp, это выходит удачно лишь для статического массива. А что будет с динамическим? Компиляторы уже и такое скушают и сделают как мы думали?

Comment: @Rang, пример не помещается в комментарии. Приведу в ответе.

Answer (score 2):

это математика указателей (операции над указателями)

[гугол_1](http://cppstudio.com/uchebniki/yazyk-programmirovaniya-s/ukazateli-v-s/), [гугол_2](http://victor192007.narod.ru/files/cpp14.html)

а лучше всего открыть книжку и почитать подробнее

Answer (score 1):

[@Rang](/users/16127/rang), смотрите (если это то, о чем Вы спрашивали)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

float *
f (float a[], float *b) 
{
  float *c = malloc(999 * sizeof(float));
  scanf ("%f %f %f %f %f %f", a, a + 1, b, &b[1], &c[0], c + 1);

  return c;
}

int 
main (int ac, char *av[]) 
{ 
  float a[2], b[2], *c = f(a, b);

  printf ("%f %f %f %f %f %f\n", 
          a[0], *(a + 1), *b, b[1], *c, c[1]);

  return puts("\nEnd") == EOF;
}
```

Запускаем

```
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ gcc tttx.c
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$ ./a.out 
1 2 3 4 5 6
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000

End
avp@avp-ubu1:~/hashcode$
```

Это то, в чем Вы сомневались?

Comment: Да, пример хороший. Я понял в чем сомневался. =)

Answer (score 0):

```
ar == ar[0]
ar+i == ar[0+i]
```